# Migrate from standalone to cluster instances of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have one node cluster of Elasticsearch
With installed Elasticsearch, kibana, apm-server
I have about 5 TB of indices

my elk version is

```
{
  "name" : "elk-old",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "qLR6jhtgS627KCq7Ls-dxQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.5.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "rpm",
    "build_hash" : "e9ccaed468e2fac2275a3761849cbee64b39519f",
    "build_date" : "2019-11-26T01:06:52.518245Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.3.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Now I want to install 3 additional nodes with hardware characteristics different to the old-elk instance:

old-elk:   10 cpu, 64 ram, 10 tb disk
new-nodes: 10 cpu, 64 ram, 5 tb disk for each one

My goal is to add three additional nodes to the cluster and store all new indices on them
old indices should be available for reading and store on old node
old indices will be automatically deleted after 1 month
and after 1 month I have to exclude old node from the cluster and shutdown it

How can I achieve this right way?

Answer (score 0):

first up, upgrade. 7.5 is [EOL](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol) and 7.15 is latest

then implement [ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html), which will handle allocation of indices, as well as rollover and retention